# Checkboxes are not responding to "check all"

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm using datatables but I don't think that's the issue. I've commented them out before and tried again and still the checkboxes don't respond.

I've tried some example code for checking all checkboxes

```
$('#test').click(function (event) {$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');});

<input id='test' type='checkbox' value='Click me' onclick='checkAll();' />Check All
```

Jquery is called on the page; at the very bottom. It was like that when I bought the theme on themeforest.

I'm really not sure what is going wrong. You have to double click on the checkboxes in order for them to be checked.

You can see the live page here with the problem:
http://rsxserver.com/logs1.php
And a live page here with the code that should make it work:
http://rsxserver.com/checkall.html

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Fyi, with a recent jQuery you can use the faster `.prop('checked', true)`.

Comment: You might want to check your jQuery code. Everytime I click the checkbox the row order changes from desc to asc and vice versa. I took code from both live pages and it works in my broswer and dreamweaver. I bet it has something to do with another script or that its not getting to click the checkbox.

Comment: @Charles it is something on the page messing it up.  You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure that this is causing your problem but you have function firing on the checkbox `onclick` event called `checkAll()` that is not defined in your page.

Try removing the call to that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').click(function (event) {$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);});
```

or better you should use the prop attribute.

Attr is not getting 'checked' anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some thing like this:

```
$('#test').live("click", function() {
                    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", false);
                    }
                });
```